# MSBuild runner changes in TeamCity 6.5

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

We've recently upgraded to TeamCity 6.5 Enterprise which started to complain about /p command line parameters in MSBuild runner steps suggesting to move those to Build Parameters. So i deleted all my /p from "Command line parameters:" and added them in Build Parameters. The problems appeared immediately with Platform param:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(483, 9): The OutputPath property is not set for project 'MyProj.csproj.teamcity'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Testing'  Platform='Any CPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
```

My build scenario includes lots of steps, some building sln-files, others .csproj/.msbuild without solution file. There is a different on how Platform parameter is treated depending on what you build (as discussed [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/503935/msbuild-inconsistent-platform-for-any-cpu-between-solution-and-project)) - "AnyCPU" or "Any CPU". As far as I understand this is the case. Can this be fixed without reverting back to /p command line parameters in the runner?

Also, this new MSBuild runner suffers from not logging the exact command line it uses making it hard to diagnose such issues. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's two related questions with answers, one for TeamCity build parameters, and another for the OutputPath property, which you should specify using OutDir instead.

- [MSBuild: OutputPath directory is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960800/msbuild-outputpath-directory-is-empty/5968228#5968228)
- [TeamCity says to use "Build Parameters" instead of "/property:" in an MSBuild step. What does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218486/teamcity-says-to-use-build-parameters-instead-of-property-in-an-msbuild-ste)